# Database trigger works on one computer but not on another computer having same database

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers, ssms

I have two servers with identical mssql databases (one was a backup of the other). I have installed "Management Studio" on both servers. I created a trigger on both servers. On one of the servers but not the other, it underlines in red "[dbo].[TriggerName]" in the query  saying **"Invalid object name 'dbo.TriggerName'"**. Coincidentally or not, the trigger misbehaves on this server with the same database. It does not underline in red when I alter the trigger on the other server.

```
USE [MYDBNAME]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TriggerName]
ON [dbo].[TableName]       
FOR UPDATE
AS
IF UPDATE([column_name])
BEGIN
UPDATE dbo.tableX SET tableXcol='True' WHERE tableXcol='False'
END
```

The stuff I have after "FOR UPDATE AS" works on one computer but not all the time on the other. It works erratically on the other computer.

Comment: That is just an issue with intellisense. You  just need to update the local cache. ctrl + shift + r

Comment: You were right. That got rid of the red underline. How can a trigger work perfectly on one machine database but poorly on another? It's almost like it works at random times and not others. Both triggers were created using the same sql. Both databases are the same in structure and data.

Comment: Not sure what you mean that it doesn't work? The trigger will do the same thing but the native intellisense is not terribly good.

Comment: The stuff I have between BEGIN and END works on one computer but not all the time on the other. It works erratically on the other computer.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Trigger code doesn't execute sometimes and not others.

Comment: The Trigger code to do operations if there is an UPDATE([column_name]) only works sometimes. It's supposed to update a table if conditions are met. It does so on one computer every time but not the other computer. The ALTER TRIGGER code gets executed though, no errors on either computer.

Comment: Then there is a logic flaw in the code. It can't work sometimes and not others.

Comment: I have only one line inside BEGIN and END. It is to UPDATE dbo.tableX SET tableXcol='True' WHERE tableXcol='False'. This works on one computer not the other server. No clues for why.

Comment: Maybe because there are no rows to update? The ONLY reason is because of different data and/or a logic error. It is simply is not going to work the way you describe.